# ReactJS TypeError: _this3.onDismissID is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, this

I'm pulling top news related to a particular search term from a website, displaying them and then adding a dismiss button beside each news so that user can delete them if they want. The code goes something like this:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

const PATH_BASE = "https://hn.algolia.com/api/v1";
const PATH_SEARCH = "/search";
const PARAM_SEARCH = "query=";
const DEFAULT_QUERY = "redux";
const url = `${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${DEFAULT_QUERY}`;
console.log(url);

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      results: null,
      searchTerm: DEFAULT_QUERY
    };
    this.setTopSearchStories = this.setTopSearchStories.bind(this);
    this.onDismissID = this.onDismissID.bind(this);
  }
  setTopSearchStories(results) {
    this.setState({ results });
  }
  onDismissID(id) {
    const updatedHits = this.state.results.hits.filter(
      (item) => item.objectID !== id
    );
    this.setState({
      result: { ...this.state.results, hits: updatedHits }
    });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    const { searchTerm } = this.state;
    fetch(`${PATH_BASE}${PATH_SEARCH}?${PARAM_SEARCH}${searchTerm}`)
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((results) => this.setTopSearchStories(results))
      .catch((error) => error);
  }
  render() {
    const { results, searchTerm } = this.state;
    if (!results) return null;
    const lists = results.hits;
    return (
      <div className="page">
        <Table list={lists} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { list } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.objectID} className="table">
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </span>
            <span>{item.author}</span>
            <span>
              <button
                onClick={() => this.onDismissID(item.objectID)}
                type="button"
              >
                Dismiss
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

It renders fine, but when I click the Dismiss button the code breaks with the error message "_this3.onDismissID is not a function" . Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue

`onDismissID` isn't defined in `Table`, it's defined in `App`.

## Solution

Seems you may want to pass `onDismissID` as a prop to `Table`.

In `App` pass an `onDismissID` prop to the `Table` component.

```
...

render() {
  const { results, searchTerm } = this.state;
  if (!results) return null;
  const lists = results.hits;
  return (
    <div className="page">
      <Table list={lists} onDismissID={this.onDismissID} /> // pass this.onDismissID
    </div>
  );
}
```

In `Table`, destructure `onDismissID` from props and attach to button click handler.

```
class Table extends Component {
  render() {
    const { list, onDismissID } = this.props; // destructure onDismissID
    return (
      <div>
        {list.map((item) => (
          <div key={item.objectID} className="table">
            <span>
              <a href={item.url}>{item.title}</a>
            </span>
            <span>{item.author}</span>
            <span>
              <button
                onClick={() => onDismissID(item.objectID)} // attach onDismissID
                type="button"
              >
                Dismiss
              </button>
            </span>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It's  so glaringly obvious, can't believe I missed it! Thank you so much!